# What is the fastest file / way to parse a large data file?

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, parsing, csv

So I am working on a GAE project. I need to look up cities, Country Names and Country Codes for sign ups, LBS, ect ...

Now I figured that putting all the information in the Datastore is rather stupid as it will be used quite frequently and its gonna eat up my datastore quotations for no reason, specially that these lists arent going to change, so its pointless to put in datastore.

Now that leaves me with a few options:

API - No budget for paid services, free ones are not exactly reliable.

Upload Parse-able file - Favorable option as I like the certainty that the data will always be there.
So I got the files needed from [GeoNames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) (link has source files for all countries in case someone needs it). The file for each country is a regular UTF-8 tab delimited file which is great.

However, now that I have the option to choose how to format and access the data, the question is:

**What is the best way to format and retrieve data systematically from a static file in a Java servelet  container ?**

The best way being the fastest, and least resource hungry method.

Valid options:

1. TXT file, tab delimited
2. XML file Static
3. Java Class with Tons of enums

I know that importing country files as Java Enums and going through their values will be very fast, but do you think this is going to affect memory beyond reasonable limits ? On the other hand, every time I need to access a record, the loop will go through a few thousand lines until it finds the required record ... reading line by line so no memory issues, but incredibly slow ... I have had some experience with parsing an excel file in a Java servelet and it took something like 20 seconds just to parse 250 records, on large scale, response time WILL timeout (no doubt about it) so is XML anything like excel ??

Thank you very much guys !! Please provide opinions, all and anything is appreciated !

Comment: No, XML parsing is in no way comparable (speedwise) to excel parsing. XML with sax/stax is incredibly fast. Why not a database? An enum is a decent choice, if the data associated with a key is too much for your memory to hold, you can use the enum simply to locate an entry, then parse it. You could even keep a list of most-used parsed in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest and fastest way would be to have the file as a static web resource file, under the `WEB-INF` folder and on application startup, have a context listener to load the file into memory.

In memory, it should be a `Map`, mapping from a key you want to search by. This will allow you like a constant access time.

Memory consumption would only matter if it is really big. A hundred thousand record for example not worth optimizing if you need to access this many times.

The static file should be plain text format or CSV, they are read and parsed most efficiently. No need XML formatting as parsing it would be slow.

If the list is really big, you can break it up into multiple, smaller files, and only parse those and only when they are required. A reasonable, easy partitioning would be to break it up by country, but any other partitioning would work (like based on its name using the first few characters from its name).

You could also consider building this `Map` in the memory once, and then serialize this map to a binary file, and include that binary file as a static resource file, and that way you would only have to deserialize this `Map` and would be no need to parse/process it as a text file and build objects yourself.

**Improvements on the data file**

An alternative to having the static resource file as a text/CSV file or a serialized Map 
data file would be to have it as a binary data file where you could create your own custom file format.

Using `DataOutputStream` you can write data to a binary file in a very compact and efficient way. Then you could use `DataInputStream` to load data from this custom file.

This solution has the advantages that the file could be much less (compared to plain text / CSV / serialized Map), and loading it would be much faster (because `DataInputStream` doesn't use number parsing from a text for example, it reads the bytes of a number directly).

Comment: Thanks alot !! Really insightful !! Love the custom binary file solution ! ... will give it a shot and let you know !

Comment: About the custom binary format: look into things like Cap'n Proto or protocol buffers: you may just be able to use that.  http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

Answer (score 1):

Hold the data in source form as XML. At start of day, or when it changes, read it into memory: that's the only time you incur the parsing cost. There are then two main options:

(a) your in-memory form is still an XML tree, and you use XPath/XQuery to query it.

(b) your in-memory form is something like a java HashMap

If the data is very simple then (b) is probably best, but it only allows you to do one kind of query, which is hard-coded. If the data is more complex or you have a variety of possible queries, then (a) is more flexible.